# Recursive flood fill on an iPad paint app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Im using recursive flood fill algorithm on my ipad painting app and it crashes  with stack overflow i think. Can someone help me solve this problem with example code or good advice because im a noob?

```
-(void)paintingBucket:(int)point point2:(int)point2 width:(int)width colorAtPoint:(UIColor *)color {

int offset = 0;
int x = point;
int y = point2;
offset = 4*((width*round(y))+round(x));

if (((x<1025 && y<705)||(x<1025) ||(y<705)) && (x>0 && y>0) && (offset<2887648)) {

    int alpha = data[offset];
    int red = data[offset + 1];
    int green = data[offset + 2];
    int blue = data[offset + 3];
    color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(green/255.0f) green:(red/255.0f) blue:(alpha/255.0f) alpha:(blue/255.0f)];

        if (![color1 isEqual: color] ) {
            return;
        } else {
            color3 = self.currentColor ;
            CGFloat r,g,b,a;
            [color3 getRed:&r green:&g blue: &b alpha: &a];
            int reda = (int)(255.0 * r);
            int greena = (int)(255.0 * g);
            int bluea = (int)(255.0 * b);
            int alphaa = (int)(255.0 * a);
            // NSLog(@" red: %u green: %u blue: %u alpha: %u", reda, greena, bluea, alphaa);

            data[offset + 3] = alphaa;
            data[offset + 2] = reda;
            data[offset + 1] = greena;
            data[offset] = bluea;
        }
    }

    [self paintingBucket:x+1 point2:y    width:width colorAtPoint:color];
    [self paintingBucket:x-1 point2:y    width:width colorAtPoint:color];
    [self paintingBucket:x   point2:y+1  width:width colorAtPoint:color];
    [self paintingBucket:x   point2:y-1  width:width colorAtPoint:color];
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the algorithm from?

Comment: from wikipedia and many sites on the web it is the same on all of them.

Comment: Post a link to the algorithm on wikipedia.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill here you go.

Comment: it isnt infinte because it works well on small objects , but it crashes on bigger ones .

Comment: you **must** convert your recursive algorithm to dynamic style. the recursive algorithms are good for demonstrate how you can solve a problem more easier but in the real environment most of them are not usable because they are eating many resources e.g. they will mess the stack, alloc the memory, use more CPU time... I won't mention there might be many pixels which are painted more than one time, totally unnecessarily. **I recommend you to not use any recursive algorithm in your code ever.**

Comment: @holex - or convert it to use tail call optimisation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) - that's when recursion _really_ becomes the way forward :)

Comment: can you give me some sample code based on my code above? or help me fix the code above? this what you just said doesnt help me really.

Comment: lost4ever, see my answer to help you. I was more pointing out to @holex that recursion isn't _always_ evil, sometimes it can be done with no stack usage whatsoever :)

Comment: @lost4ever, read more information about the **[dynamic programming here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)**. haven't you leant it on the university?

Comment: @deanWombourne, it is not definitely _evil_, just pointlessly wasting the resources. if the point is to waste the resources, the recursion would be the best choice. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking the function into the fillRight and fillLeft methods isn't a long-term solution because if the image gets bigger, overflow may occur again.

I'd recommend using a faster flood-fill algorithm. The 4-Way flood fill described on Wikipedia is easy to implement, but goes through every point four times.

I'd recommend using a scanline fill: see http://lodev.org/cgtutor/floodfill.html - Scanline Floodfill Algorithm With Stack. I replaced my 4-way flood fill in my drawing app and it now is much faster and fills a 1024x768px area in less than a second. Of course, the speed may vary depending on your implementation.

And at last, some notes:

1.You can use CGPoint to store points in an array.

```
CGPoint point=CGPointMake(100, 50); //Declare a point and put a value in it
```

Then you can get and set the x and y values using point.x and point.y

2.Use an array to store the points to be checked as deanWombourne suggested.

```
NSMutableArray * pointsToCheck=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//Initialise the array
[pointsToCheck addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:start]];//Assuming you have a CGPoint start, you need to convert it to a NSValue before you put it into the array like [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]

while ([pointsToCheck count]>0){//While there are points to be checked:
    NSValue * pointValue=[pointsToCheck objectAtIndex:0];//Get the point: It doesn't matter if you get the first or last item
    [pointsToCheck removeObjectAtIndex:0];//Remove the point from the queue so we won't go through it again

    CGPoint point=[pointValue CGPointValue];//Get the CGPoint from the NSValue object

    //Implement your algorithm here: check for neighbour points, paint the current point or whatever. I'd recommend  using scanline fill - see above
    //When you need to add a point to the queue (If it was a recursive function, then you'd call the function from itself with different parameters) use:
    [pointsToCheck addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newPoint];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive example fo making this a dynamic algorithm, not recursive.

```
NSMutableArray *pointsToRender = [NSMutableArray new];
[pointsToRender addObject:startingPoint];

while (pointsToRender.length>0) {

    // Get a point from the array and fill it
    MyPoint *point = [pointsToRender lastObject];
    [pointsToRender removeLastObject];
    [self drawColor:color atPoint:point];

    // Are any surrounding points needing to be filled?
    if (point 1px above) needs to be filled
        [pointsToRender addObject : point1Above];
    .. repeat for the other three points

}
```

Yea, this is half objective C and half pseudocode, sorry. But you get the idea. In English it's this :

- Make an array of points that you need to fill, containing the start point.
- For each point

  - Fill it
  - Remove it from the array
  - Look at it's neighbours. Add each neighbour to the array if it also needs to be filled
  - repeat until your points to be filled array is empty

This will consume heap, not stack.

Comment: OK i understand the basic idea behind this but im not sure i will know how to implement this . i will try if i dont succeed can u help me some more? 
The data that contains bitmap info is of type usigned char and it isnt an object so i cant put it it NSMutableArray is there any way to do that? i will try to implement this and will get back with my result.

Comment: You could take a look at `NSValue` to store arbitrary C data in an object. And I'm storing a point (x, y) not a a char in my mutable array. You could also just make a class of your own to hold an x and y value (I called mine `MyPoint` :)

Comment: better than the original solution but in that case there are still many points which will be painted two times as well. not too efficient. :) anyway, I don't want to be heartless but the final algorithm should be implemented by the asker using the given guidelines because this is not the "give-me-the-full-working-code-because-I-do-not-know-how-I-can-implement-it" site. :(

Comment: I did use the word 'naive' in the first sentence of my answer ;) And my answer is very much a pointer in the right direction, not a complete solution by any means! To start with, modifying NSMutableArray that many times in a tight loop probably not the most efficient thing to do  . . . and you certainly wouldn't want to make an new object to put into a mutable array for every point you wanted filled! This probably isn't the most performant algorithm ever written!

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem using this two methods. it is a little slow but im working on optimizing this solution.

```
-(void)fillRight:(int)x point2:(int)y witdh:(int)width {
int x1 = x;
int y1 = y;

int offset = 4*((width*round(y1))+round(x1));
int alpha = data[offset];
int red = data[offset + 1];
int green = data[offset + 2];
int blue = data[offset + 3];
color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(green/255.0f) green:(red/255.0f) blue:(alpha/255.0f) alpha:(blue/255.0f)];
// NSLog(@"%d %d %@ %@", x,y,color,color1);

if([color1 isEqual: color])
{
    color3 = self.currentColor ;
    CGFloat r,g,b,a;
    [color3 getRed:&r green:&g blue: &b alpha: &a];
    int reda = (int)(255.0 * r);
    int greena = (int)(255.0 * g);
    int bluea = (int)(255.0 * b);
    int alphaa = (int)(255.0 * a);
    // NSLog(@" red: %u green: %u blue: %u alpha: %u", reda, greena, bluea, alphaa);

    data[offset + 3] = alphaa;
    data[offset + 2] = reda;
    data[offset + 1] = greena;
    data[offset] = bluea;


    [self fillRight:++x1 point2:y1 witdh:width];
    x1 = x1 - 1 ;
    [self fillRight:x1 point2:y1-1 witdh:width];
    [self fillRight:x1 point2:y1+1 witdh:width];
}
}

-(void)fillLeft:(int)x point2:(int)y width:(int)width {
int x1 = x;
int y1 = y;

int offset = 4*((width*round(y1))+round(x1));
int alpha = data[offset];
int red = data[offset + 1];
int green = data[offset + 2];
int blue = data[offset + 3];
color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(green/255.0f) green:(red/255.0f) blue:(alpha/255.0f) alpha:(blue/255.0f)];
// NSLog(@"%d %d %@ %@", x,y,color,color1);

if([color1 isEqual: color])
{
    color3 = self.currentColor ;
    CGFloat r,g,b,a;
    [color3 getRed:&r green:&g blue: &b alpha: &a];
    int reda = (int)(255.0 * r);
    int greena = (int)(255.0 * g);
    int bluea = (int)(255.0 * b);
    int alphaa = (int)(255.0 * a);
    // NSLog(@" red: %u green: %u blue: %u alpha: %u", reda, greena, bluea, alphaa);

    data[offset + 3] = alphaa;
    data[offset + 2] = reda;
    data[offset + 1] = greena;
    data[offset] = bluea;

    [self fillLeft:--x1 point2:y1 width:width];
    x1 = x1 + 1 ;
    [self fillLeft:x1 point2:y1-1 width:width];
    [self fillLeft:x1 point2:y1+1 width:width];
}
}
```

Comment: did you got a solution, i'm trying to figure out this form many days, but i'm always getting memory overflow and solutions are very slow

Comment: i never got around to optimise the solution because the project was dropped, sorry. This code works so you could try to optimise it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer using the A* algorithm for flood fills. Basically, you color the visited nodes. while searching for path to a point that is known to be outside of your fill area. (-1, -1 does the trick)